# How exactly is this code working to reverse a string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, reverse

```py
def reverse(x):
    output = ""
    for c in x:
        output = c + output

    return output

print(reverse("Hello"))
```

This code works fine to reverse a string in Python, I just can't seem to understand why it is working and how.

If, for example, I iterate through a string, usually it will iterate and print starting from "H" and work its way down to "O." How is it that here, it's going backwards?

Comment: The key is in `output = c + output`. The character is concatenated to the beginning of the output string instead of to the end, resulting in a reversed string. The easiest way to reverse a string, however, is `x[::-1]`.

Comment: I would suggest using this site - [python tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) - for this kind of problems. Simply copy your code there and you can visualize it step by step! Very helpful to understand small programs like this :)

Answer (score 2):

If you put some output to your loop you can see how the code is filling up the string.

```
def reverse(x):
    output = ""
    for c in x:
        output = c + output
        print(output)

    return output

print(reverse("Hello"))
```

So you can see how it works:

```
H
eH
leH
lleH
olleH
olleH
```

So you ad the last one to the end and that is how you reverse it. If you switch the following line in your loop:

```
output = output + c
```

Then the order is not reversed:

```
H
He
Hel
Hell
Hello
Hello
```

Answer (score 1):

This loop goes over the characters of the string, and for each character **prepends** it to the current result.

Let's track the value of `output` as we go over the characters (the `c` values):

```
c output
H H
e eH
l leH
l lleH
o olleH
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time a character goes into the loop, it gets appended into the output.
Initially output = ""

So for iteration 1: output = ""

```
c = "H"
output = "H" + "" = "H"
```

Iteration 2: output = "H"

```
c = "e"
output = "e" + "H" = "eH"
```

Iteration 3: output = "eH"

```
c = "l"
output = "l" + "eH" = "leH"
```

Iteration 4: output = "leH"

```
c = "l"
output = "l" + "leH" = "lleH"
```

Iteration 5: output = "lleH"

```
c = "o"
output = "o" + "lleH" = "olleH"
```

So the final result comes out to "olleH"